# Autoresize text in qml for RichText type

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to create a text element with rich text that auto-fits font size to fill the window its in.  The text is of varying length and wraps to new line if it's too long. I need to scale the font so it fits in the same line, regardless of its size. If  `textFormat: Text.RichText;` is not set this works fine. Is it possible to get this functionality when rich text is enabled.

```
Rectangle {
    width: parent.width
    height: 1
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    opacity: 0.1
}
    Text {
        id: testName;
        anchors.left: parent.left;
        anchors.right: parent.right;
        font {
            family: globalSettings.font + " Medium"
            pixelSize: 20
            letterSpacing: 0.2
        }
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter;
        fontSizeMode: Text.HorizontalFit;
        text: name;
        textFormat: Text.RichText;
        wrapMode: Text.Wrap;
        width: parent.width;
    }
```

Comment: The [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#fontSizeMode-prop) explicitly say it won't work with RichText. You could try doing something manual with a `TextMetrics` or `FontMetrics` object.

Comment: @JarMan yes that was the basics of the question, is there another method when using Rich Text. Apologies if question didn't make that clear. Thanks I will look into those mentioned.